# Django movable blocks layout

Tags: django, django-templates

I wanted to know if anyone has ever done this before and if its even possible to do using django.

I have a layout of information with 3 blocks of data, but i wanted to give the user the option to move the blocks around in the way that the user see how they would like the data displayed.

Maybe user A would like the first 2 blocks to be on top and the last one to be on the bottom

User B would like the bottom block to be on top and the other 2 to be on the bottom

I can't really find any documentation on how to do something like that, does any one have any information to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put `block_sequence` ( for example `[3,2,0,1]`) into the context and use a template  like this:

```
{% for block in block_sequence %}
    {% if block == 0 %}
        {% include 'wherever/block0.html' %}
    {% elif block == 1 %}
        {% include 'wherever/block1.html' %}
    ...
    {% else %}
        <p><b>Programming error! Found block == {{block}} in
              block_sequence
        </b></p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

`block_sequence` would probably be kept in the User's profile (a JSONfield, or a CharField with trivial parsing to create a list), and you'd need to give the user a view where he can specify and save his preferred sequence.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import random

def play_game():
    print("Welcome to the Number Guessing Game!")
    print("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.")
    secret_number = random.randint(1, 100)
    attempts = 0

    while True:
        guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
        attempts += 1

        if guess < secret_number:
            print("Too low! Try a higher number.")
        elif guess > secret_number:
            print("Too high! Try a lower number.")
        else:
            print(f"Congratulations! You guessed the number in {attempts} attempts!")
            break

play_game()
```